# How to see what label color is on a file/folder from within Termnal (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, terminal, label

I want to include in a script a check for a file input to see if the file/folder has a color set and if it does, which one... (I don't need help with the creation of this script, just need the command to check what color the label is).

eg, like these colors (grey):
http://img.skitch.com/20090923-t1xsphn47tdq64b8ksb43wh3e8.png

I would like to avoid using apple script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using xattr... for instance, I have a directory named "Foo", and I made its label red in the Finder. Then I did:

```
wilPureSex% xattr -p com.apple.FinderInfo Foo
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Then I made it blue, and you can see the relevant byte change:

```
wilPureSex% xattr -p com.apple.FinderInfo Foo
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

-Wil

Comment: Oh wow, this is going deep, thanks.
But seems to do the trick.
Will the color always be shown on that same byte?

Comment: I have no idea, I just started playing with it and this is what I discovered.

Answer (score 5):

```
mdls -name kMDItemFSLabel -raw "[filename or directory]"
```

... will output the number of the label. assign it to a variable like this:

```
LABEL_NUMBER=$(mdls -name kMDItemFSLabel -raw "[filename or directory]")
echo $LABEL_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use "mdls *filename*" and look for the kMDItemFSLabel value.  I'm looking for a way to change the label via command line if anyone knows of a way.

Answer (score 2):

I made this script to return the label index of the file or folder as an integer where:

```
0 = no colour
1 = orange
2 = red
3 = yellow
4 = blue
5 = purple
6 = green
7 = grey
```

All you need to do is:

```
#!
getlabel() {
    osascript - "$@" << EOF
    on run argv
        tell application "Finder"
            set theArg to POSIX file ((do shell script "pwd") & "/" & argv) as alias
                set labelIndex to (get label index of theArg)
                do shell script("echo " & labelIndex)
            end tell
        end run
EOF
}
```

So now you can do stuff like:

```
#!
if [ `~/bin/getlabel $1` == 2 ]; then
    echo yup
else
    echo nope
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip! In my use case, I changed `set theArg to POSIX file ((do shell script "pwd") & "/" & argv) as alias` to `set theArg to POSIX file (argv) as alias` so that the script uses the absolute path of the file.